# How do you assign characterAtIndex to NSString variable?

Tags: objective-c

I've looked at several posts to answer my question but i keep getting errors.

I basically have an NSString that holds 2 characters...

```
myString = @"ABC";
```

All I want to do is assign the first character in myString to another NSString variable...

```
NSString *firstChar;
firstChar = [myString characterAtIndex:0];
```

I get this error when i do this:

> Incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'unichar *' (aka 'unsigned short *') from 'unichar' (aka 'unsigned short')

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is developer.apple.com down again or something? The return type of `characterAtIndex:` is clearly noted in the documentation...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about (not) reading the official documentation.


Comment: I read the official documentation, just didn't understand the unichar part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSString`'s `characterAtIndex:` returns a `unichar`, not a string, so you can't just assign it to another string. You need to create a string from it first:

```
NSString *myString = @"ABC";
unichar firstChar = [myString characterAtIndex:0];
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithCharacters:&firstChar length:1];
```

Of course, as DarkDust says, you can also use `substringWithRange:` to get a string from a subrange of a string:

```
[myString subStringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1)]; // to get the first character
[myString subStringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, 2)]; // to get the second and third characters
```

Answer (score 1):

The `characterAtIndex:` method returns a `unichar` (an integer representation of the character). What you want is [`-[NSString substringWithRange:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/substringWithRange%3a), like `[myString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1)];`